# SAS stored process result-set dump

Tags: sas, resultset, dump, data-dump

The task I try to accomplish is exporting the result-set calculated by a remote SAS machine via any tool to a CSV/XLSX file.

The result-set I'm talking about is at the size of 500K rows and 100MB XLSX approximate file size.

The SAS Server details:

Operating System:   Linux for X64

Product:    SAS 9.2 64-bits, Rev. 920_11w03

Error code I received from MS Excel (when tried to get the result-set via SAS Add-in for Office 4.2) is shown below:

`System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.InternalCopy(String str)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLIQData.XMLCSV.CreateValueElement(Char ch, ArrayList valueList, Values& values, StringBuilder& sb, Boolean& inDataString)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLIQData.XMLCSV.TokenizeString(String csvString, ArrayList valueList, ValuesList& valuesList, Int32& valuesCount, Boolean isOLAP)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLIQData.XMLCSV.LoadElement(ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelement(String name, XmlNode node, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelements(String name, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLIQData.XMLEmbeddedData.LoadElement(ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelement(String name, XmlNode node, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelement(String name, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLIQData.LoadElement(ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelement(String name, XmlNode node, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLData.LoadElement(ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelement(String name, XmlNode node, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLReportElement.LoadSubelements(String name, XMLReportElement xmlClass, ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLSASReport.LoadElement(ReportElement parent)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XMLParse.CreateDOM(Stream file, String fragment, Hashtable customObjectMap)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XML.ReadReport(Stream inputStream, Hashtable customObjectMap)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XML.ReadReport(FileInfo file, Hashtable customObjectMap, String prefixUniqueId)
   at SAS.Report.Models.XML.XML.ReadReport(String filename, Hashtable customObjectMap, String uniqueIdPrefix)
   at SAS.AMO.Reports.SASReport.FromXML(String filename, Hashtable customObjectMap, Int32 fileId)
   at SAS.OfficeAddin.ExcelReports.ExcelSASReport.FromXml(String filename, Int32 fileId)
   at SAS.OfficeAddin.ExcelAddin.OpenSASReport(JobContext context)
   at SAS.OfficeAddin.ExcelAddin.ProcessResults(JobContext context)
   at SAS.OfficeAddin.OfficeAddinBase.PostProcessJob(JobContext jobContext, Boolean promptOnErrors)`

Please advise on any software that can help make the data accessible
(Where is the final target is to make pivot tables from the data retrieved from the SAS stored process).

Comment: Create a problem ticket with SAS Tech support to get a solution to this problem.  Here is a link:  http://support.sas.com/ctx/supportform//createForm.

Comment: they said the problem with Excel is known, I'm looking for a BI system that can pull data from the SAS SPs (and yes, I know it will be a second layer of BI system)